# Corner banner css

Tags: html, css, transparency

I'm creating a corner banner for use in a few websites, and I'm using the following CSS method to create a triange;

```
#corner-ad-btn {
position: absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
width:0px;
height:0px;
border-top: 420px solid #fff;
border-left: 420px solid transparent;
z-index: 100;}
```

Which I'm them using in the html as;

```
<a href="#" id="corner-ad-btn">
```

This sits on top of the actual jpg ad. It works great, except for the button is active for the whole square area, which will cover too much of the site. Is it possible to have the transparent area non-clickable?

I've tried another method where the did is rotated and hidden, but this requires an a hidden overflow on the body, which won't work on the sites.

Here is a  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjBX4/)

Comment: I don't know if there is a better solution but you could possibly look into the `<map>` and `<area>` tags to create an image map over the image

Comment: Ah, yes. Hadn't thought about that... I will check that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample triangle button over an image using the `<map>` and `<area>` tags, based on my suggestion in the comments:

```
<img id="corner-ad-btn" width="420" height="420" usemap="corner-ad-map" src="#" />
<map name="corner-ad-map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,420,0,420,420" href="#"></area>
</map>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjBX4/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Can you make a div around the link and give that a hidden overflow, instead of putting the hidden overflow on the body?

Comment: Why'd you make it 1000px wide & high though..?

Comment: For no specific reason. It's a quick demo where the OP can see if this method works for him. I'm not sure if he want to use it for the `<body>` tag or for an other elements which contains this corner + the image. Thus the ratio is inrelevant for this case.

Comment: Hi. I tried the above, but was still having overflow issues. I think it may have been due to the other content, but I just couldn't get it to play nice. Thanks for the suggestions though, I ended up going for the <map> <area> option